# Stop dragging picturebox c #

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I have a picturebox and movement just right and to the left, but when moving it to the left or right edge of the picturebox appears in the middle of the form , as the picture below

This thus
[image]

what I want is when moving left or right when the board of picturebox were in the same position of the board form the image can not be more moves , just to the other lado.Conforme the image below

[image]

Follows the script:

```
    private void imagemPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            x = e.X;
            //y = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void imagemPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {             
            imagemPictureBox.Left += (e.X - x);

            //imagemPictureBox.Top += (e.Y - y);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Could you please clearly explain what you want to happen, what is happening and any additional information that might help.

Comment: I hope that is clearer

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  // the point in the PB where we grab it:
  Point mDown;

  void imagemPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      // grab the pb
      mDown = e.Location;
  }

  void imagemPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    // new position:
    int x = imagemPictureBox.Left + e.X - mDown.X;
    int y = imagemPictureBox.Top  + e.Y - mDown.Y;

    // limit to form size:
    x = Math.Min(Math.Max(x, 0), this.ClientSize.Width -  imagemPictureBox.Width);
    y = Math.Min(Math.Max(y, 0), this.ClientSize.Height - imagemPictureBox.Height);

    // move the pb:
    imagemPictureBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
  }

  void imagemPictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      //release it (optional)
      mDown = Point.Empty;
  }
```